# How do you say, "Do you need an interpreter?" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, words

How do you say, "Do you need an interpreter?" in Japanese?
I put it in google translate and it came up as 通訳が必要ですか. Is this correct? I don't trust google translate lol..

Answer (score 1):

I've only recently started studying the language, but that looks ok I think.  It translates more literally to "Is an interpreter needed?".  You could start the sentence addressing the person by their name+さん, though I'm not sure if it would be correct to put them as the topic of the sentence or not. I hope someone else can elaborate further.